# Argument error in Flex when trying to access xml data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Flex application which shows map .I can also ZoomIn or ZoomOut throughout the map.Currently i am accessing the zoom values from xml file,

Code Below.

Code for accessing XML file.

```
private var xmlProperties:XML;
private function init():void {

    sendRequest("properties.xml", propertyFileLoaded);

}



private function propertyFileLoaded(evt:ResultEvent):void {

    showBusy(false);

    xmlProperties = XML(evt.result);

        .......

        .......
}
```

Mxml part for accessing zoom levels.

```
<esri:LOD level="8" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_8').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_8').@y}" />
                        <esri:LOD level="9" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_9').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_9').@y}" />
                        <esri:LOD level="10" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_10').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_10').@y}" />
                        <esri:LOD level="11" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_11').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_11').@y}" />
                        <esri:LOD level="12" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_12').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_12').@y}" />
                        <esri:LOD level="13" resolution="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_13').@x}" scale="{xmlProperties..layer.(@name == 'LAYER_13').@y}" />
```

XML Data.

```
.....
.....
<layer name="LEVEL_10" x="152.87405657041106" y="577790.554289" />
<layer name="LEVEL_11" x="76.43702828507324" y="288895.277144" />
.....
.....
```

Previously i have hard coded the zoom level values like this,

```
<esri:LOD level="7" resolution="453.4534" scale="3.45346345" />
```

But when i tried to access values from XML its showing error ,

```
Argument Error:Error #2004: One of the parameter is invalid.
```

How to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: may be replace _LAYER_8_ with _LEVEL_8_ as in XML Data?

Comment: no ..its not working...I think the Map Zoom layer is loading before the xml file.How to load xml file loading function at the very beginning of Application.So that xmlProperties will have data when trying to access from <esri:LOD  >